# How can I calculate an anniversary with PHP date() and display it in an HTML paragraph?

Tags: php

I can't find anything here that I've been able to adapt for my case. I would like to dynamically update a paragraph on my homepage that reads along the lines of "2023 is the 45th anniversary...".

I tried the following:

`<?php echo date("Y") ?> will see the <?php echo date("Y", strtotime("-1978 year")) ?> anniversary of...`

But that returns "2023 will see the 0045 anniversary of...". Is there any way to have 45th (leading zeros removed, and st/nd/rd/th appended) in a "simple" inline PHP snippet, or does it require something like javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google and a peek at the PHP manual gets you to

```
<?php
$nf = new NumberFormatter('en_GB', NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
$otherYear = 1978;
echo date("Y") . 
     ' will see the ' . 
     $nf->format( (int)date("Y", strtotime("-$otherYear year")) ) . 
    ' anniversary of... ';
?>
```

RESULT

```
2023 will see the 45th anniversary of...
```

You dont have to code PHP all in one line, making it readable will make it maintainable.

**NOTE**

the PHP extension `extension=intl` must be activeated in your `php.ini`

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you. I originally got an error as the site is (was) running an older version of PHP (as it has an old phpBB2 forum installed), but I upped it to PHP7.0 and everything still seems to work. I haven't just blindly copy & pasted it. I will study the code to understand how it works. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Make sure you have the ICU `intl` extension enabled as `NumberFormatter` is part of it.

Comment: @Jim The above code worked fine, but I note that 'extension=php_intl.dll' is commented out in my php.ini file. Is there a specific reason to uncomment it?

Comment: Well then you might be looking in the wrong `php.ini` file. That code will only work if `php_intl` is not activated In other word only when the `extension=php_intl.dll` does not have a `;` comment in front of it

Comment: It couldn't work without it being enabled. Some systems have multiple php.ini files. One for CLI, one for the web server, etc. You might be looking at one that is not related the the way your code is being run.